# Google Sheets - If Column A current row is empty, use nearest value above in column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get Google Sheets to combine two columns, replace spaces and special characters with dashes in order to improve SEO.  I have run into an issue where if column A is empty (usually due to the value of the cell being implied by the nearest non-empty cell above it) column B combines with blank.

I need a way for column A to search up from the current cell, find the nearest value above the current cell and combine that value with the value of column B in the original row of column A.  I have attached a picture so it makes more sense.

I am currently using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"", LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A:A & "-" & B:B, " ", "-")), ""))
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

[image: What I am currently getting]

[image: What I want to get]

Answer (score 1):

You can use SCAN to consider previous value when value is empty:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B<>"", LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SCAN(,A:A,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="",a,v))) & "-" & B:B, " ", "-")), ""))
```

PS: I replaced first condition of IF statement, so it considers B column instead

[image]